# How to perform CAP curve analysis in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, optimization, data-mining, roc

I'm trying to plot in R a cumulative accuracy profile (CAP) Curve.
Additional, after I will build the curve, how am I calculate the AR.

Comment: check out this answer, I think that what you need
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268031/creating-a-lift-chart-in-r

Comment: I have written a package for calculating the Accuracy Rate and plotting the CAP curve. You can download it from GitHub. library(devtools) install_github("Marcyyyl/CAPcurve") library(CAPcurve)
[![Example CAP curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kafRv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kafRv.png)